# Label animation inside the TableViewcell

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, ios-animations

I want to achieve the animation same as google calendar.

Here is the GIF :https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmOps.gif

I’m using tableView to populate the data. I’ve added the left label to first row of section.I want the label to be animated as user scroll the tableview.

Can anyone provide a knowledge, a bit of code for getting this animation.

Thank you!